# Major C# Errors in my browser

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Here are the errors I get when debugging:

Error   1   Too many characters in character literal
Error   2   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.Navigate(string)' has some invalid arguments
Error   3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'char' to 'string'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BroZer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Reload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Refresh();
        }

        private void Go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
        }

        private void Back_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoBack();
        }

        private void Forward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoForward();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate('https://www.google.com/search?&ie=UTF-8&q= + (textBox1.Text)');
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

All errors are in line 41.

Comment: Uh, my C# is a little rusty, but just looking at the third error, doesn't it think that you're trying to input a character into Navigate as opposed to a String?

Comment: You don't get it when you debug it. You get it when the code is compiled.

Answer (score 7):

> 'https://www.google.com/search?&ie=UTF-8&q= + (textBox1.Text)'

I have an idea of what you think this should do, but it's wrong.

`'x'` denotes a *character* literal (i.e., an instance of `char`, not `string`.  In this case, the character `x`), yet you use it like a string, and then want to interpolate `textbox1.Text` into it, yet C# doesn't support this type of direct interpolation at all.  You wanted to write:

```
// concatenate a string literal and a string variable
"https://www.google.com/search?&ie=UTF-8&q=" + textBox1.Text;
```

The next two error messages are a direct result of the first.  The error messages are quite clear here, you would do well to search for what they mean and attempt to deduce the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Dammit. FGTW. And here I was, about to comment, when "1 new answer" pops up ^^'

Comment: @blahman: Gotta be quick! No sense in posting an answer as a comment. :D

Comment: Haha, true! But mine would have been nowhere near as complete as your's so I'm glad I held back to not misinform the OP =)

Answer (score 5):

Change the line

```
webBrowser1.Navigate('https://www.google.com/search?&ie=UTF-8&q= + (textBox1.Text)');
```

to

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(string.Format("https://www.google.com/search?&ie=UTF-8&q={0}", textBox1.Text);
```

This is because the Navigate method expects String or Uri as it's parameters ([WebBrowser.Navigate Method @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigate.aspx)) you have sent through a char.

Comment: If it worked you should accept an answer not necessarily mine either.

Answer (score 3):

```
The error is line webBrowser1.Navigate('https://www.google.com/search?&ie=UTF-8&q= + (textBox1.Text)');
```

You are using single quote ' instead of "

Please use it this way:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com/search?&ie=UTF-8&q=" + textBox1.Text);
```

Just for your knowledge in C# '' is for Char and "" is for string

```
e.g char c = 'C'; and string s = "something";
```